# Could the new fighter jets offered to Ukraine by the EU be used to target Russia directly?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

In light of the recent events ([the Ukrainian parliament on Monday tweeted that Europe was sending 70 fighter planes to Ukraine](https://www.politico.com/news/2022/02/28/ukrainian-pilots-arrive-in-poland-to-pick-up-donated-fighter-jets-00012560))

Would using the jets to target Russia directly (being more offensive than defensive), be a questionable move, given that Ukraine is currently considered a victim?

Comment: It's a war. There is no law to restrict the fighting zone to the soil of the attacked country. The fight can be brought to any area of the two fighting countries (in principle). But strategically this seems unrealistic. Ukraine is on the defense since day one. Forget any offensive, it won't happen. Have you compared military strengths of both countries lately? This question seems to be based on rather unrealistic assumptions.

Comment: So, basically, you are asking us about our opinion of the public opinion in case a hypothetical event was to happen?  Sorry, this is a bit off topic for here, voting to close (no DV).  But it was interesting to learn about this new transfer nevertheless.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Well, the title is "could", which is not opinion based. As for the "would", it depends on its interpretation...

Comment: "As for the "would", it depends on its interpretation..." Why would the would depend on a interpretation? It's just a matter of statistics. Given certain circumstances, it would happen. But I don't really think they are given at all. So it's more like a "Could an asteroid fall on the Earth again soon" could.

Comment: It depends on the terms of use for the sale, but Ukraine can already do that with their own aircraft and no so small arsenal of ballistic missiles (they have some 500).

Comment: You write the title as if those planes are anywhere close to "new". I think it's highly debatable how many can even be flown at the moment.

Comment: The link mentions some (slightly outdated) air superiority fighters with a limited bombing capacity, and some (slightly outdated) close air support aircraft. They can be used to attack beyond the border, but they are not deep strike aircraft. Voting to reopen, by the way, because the offensive vs. defensive potential is not just a matter of opinions.

Answer (score 5):

Given that Ukraine and Russia are currently in a state of war, the answer is "yes". You can attack the other country even if you are the one that's attacked.

Examples in history:

- The Confederate States of America staged two invasions of the Union in the American Civil War, as well as several raids.
- Nazi Germany invaded France in World War 2, and at the end of that war, French troops were in Germany.
- [Doolittle raid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doolittle_Raid), a raid by US aircraft on mainland Japan in the early stages of World War 2. This shows you don't have to be winning to attack, even if the damage you do is minimal and the effect is mainly psychological.

So yes, if Ukraine wants to, they can attack Russia directly with the aircraft instead of fighting a defensive war. This will come with logistical difficulties of course, e.g. how are you going to get your aircraft into Russia without the Russian air force or anti-air weapons interfering? - but it's still possible. The question then becomes "will Ukraine do it?" which is not an answerable question unless you are the Ukrainian leadership.

Comment: The examples are somewhat outdated: what was commonplace in WW2 or even during the Vietnam war, is often treated as war crimes today. E.g., strategic bombing was an open western policy of incurring suffering on civilians, in order to induce Germany and Japan to surrender. So bloody it was, that Japan was unimpressed by the bombing of Hiroshima (which in itself would be a war crime by modern standards). This is not to say that the answer is wrong - military objects within Russia are probably still legitimate targets... but Ukraine might more lose than win by doing it.

Comment: @RogerVadim: there are reports they fired a Tochka at the Millerovo Airbase airbase already. It's possible that instead the Russians had a ground accident like a bomb going off, since a Su-30 was was shown on fire on the ground, who knows.

Comment: @Fizz Great [addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millerovo_air_base_attack).